# Load a remote video with guzzle in laravel 5

Tags: php, video, laravel-5.4, guzzle6

I am trying to use guzzle to load and play a remote video uploaded in a subdomain (subdomain.domain.com) to a location in the main domain (domain.com).

I am finding it difficult to get the video to play.

The video player in the blade file has the following url for the video source

```
`<source src="{{url('video/'.$token.'/'.$videoname)}}" type="{{$video_mime_type}}">
```

....`

The route for the source leads to a controller with the following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;
use Response;
use File;
use GuzzleHttp\Mimetypes;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;
use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Utils;

class ResourceController extends Controller
{


public function show_video_api($videoname)
{       
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://subdomain.domain.com/api/']);

    $resp = $client->request('GET',"video/".$videoname,['stream'=>true]);

    $body=$resp->getBody();
    echo $body;

   }

}
```

The subdomain api methos is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Log;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{

public function video($videoname)
{

    return response()->file(storage_path("app/lesson-files/$videoname"));
}
}
```

However, the video is not playing. I need this sorted out as fast as I can so I will appreciate any assistance to figure it out.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think in Laravel you have to return a `Response`, not just print something to standard output (not sure if it's buffered). Do create a `Response` object instead of just `echo`ing content.

But it's better to look at [`sink` option in Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#sink) and use it to output the response directly in cURL, skipping PHP.

But... You probably don't want to do it in PHP in any way, because it's a really slow way to serve video. Take a look at nginx, it's very flexible and fast for such use cases.